# Async/Await isn't waiting for subsequent request to finish before running

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios, es6-promise

I'm trying to use Axios interceptors to request the CSRF then Bearer Token if it's not already stored in local-storage.

It mostly works, however the requests don't seem to wait for `authToken = await fetchAuthToken();`  to resolve before continuing, and I can't seem to figure out why.

What I'm expecting is the `console.log("this")` will run first, then `console.log("then this")`;

Everything is defined, I've omitted parts for brevity.

```
function fetchAuthToken() {
  authToken = checkLocalStorage("token", false);
  if (isFetchingToken) return false;
  if (authToken) return authToken;

  return apiClient
    .get("/csrf-cookie")
    .then(() => {
      apiClient.get("/token").then((res) => {
        authToken = res.data.bearer_token;
        localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(res.data.bearer_token));
        console.log('this')
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {});
}

// Request interceptor for API calls
apiClient.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    if (config.url.includes("/csrf-cookie") || config.url.includes("/token")) {
      isFetchingToken = true;
      return config;
    }

    if (!authToken) {
      authToken = await fetchAuthToken();
      console.log('then this')
    }

    config.headers = {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
    };
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: Missing `return` for your token request, ie `return apiClient.get("/token")...`. You should also `return authToken` in the following `.then()`

Comment: also, flatten your promise chain in `apiClient` for better looking code